# Setup Subversion VPS Centos

Tags: svn, centos, vps

I have a weird problem installing subversion on my VPS. I tried to install it with these steps: http://www.directadmin.com/forum/showthread.php?t=30972&p=157056#post157056. But I got an error when I'm trying to restart apache after completing the steps:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 166 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: 
Cannot load /usr/lib/apache/mod_dav_svn.so into server:
/usr/lib/apache/mod_dav_svn.so: undefined symbol: svn_error_purge_tracing
```

I'm working on it for days now but really can't get it work.
Does anyone have any clue about this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working now, but not based on the mod_dav_svn module from Apache. Everyone else who has this issue take a look at using SVNServe for your SVN setup.